# Solve this Inequality

Tags: inequality

I am not sure how to solve this equation. Any ideas

$$(1+n) + 1+(n-1) + 1+(n-2) + 1+(n-3) + 1+(n-4) + \cdots + 1+(n-n) \ge 1000$$
Assuming $1+n = a$
The equation can be made to looks like

$$a+(a-1)+(a-2)+(a-3)+(a-4)+\cdots+(a-n)  \ge 1000$$

How to proceed ahead, or is there another approach to solve this?

Comment: Luckily, addition is associative and commutative. Get rid of the parentheses and try to do some cancelling. Hint: what is the sum 1 + 2 +...+n?

Comment: This is the simplest case of the arithmetic series, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series for detailed explanations.

Comment: Also note the last term in your sum is $(a-n)=(a-(a-1))=1$

Comment: So my attempt was to simplify it to (n+1)a-n(n+1)/2 >= 1000, is that right?

Comment: It's not an equation; it's an inequality.

Comment: @aadidasu Yes, now presumably you want to find the smallest such n satIsfying that inequality. You should plug n+1 back in for a.

Comment: List the terms in your sequence, *concretely*, starting from the end. You will see what's going on.  You don't *really* need $a$, sum is $(n+1)(n+2)/2$. Then calculate for a few values of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example (probably not the most elegant though...) way to solve this. First either you write $(n+1)a-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and replace $a$ by $n+1$ or you just realize replacing $a$ by $n+1$ in your second inequation that the left side is $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$.

Your inequality is then 
$$(n+1)^2+(n+1)\geq 2000$$

You can for example consider the polynomial $P(X)=X^2+X-2000$ and you want to study the sign of this, which should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will do it as the following,

$$
\begin{align}
&(1+n) + 1+(n-1) + 1+(n-2) + 1+(n-3) + 1+(n-4) + \cdots + 1+(n-n)\\
=&(1+n) + [1+(n-1) + 1+(n-2) + 1+(n-3) + 1+(n-4) + \cdots + 1+(n-n)]\\
=&(n+1) + [n+(n-1)+\cdots+2+1]\\
=&\frac{(n+1)[1+(n+1)]}{2}\\
=&\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} 
\end{align}
$$

Now you can go on with Rolando's answer.